# Creating an azure php web role

Tags: php, azure

I have somewhat successfully followed this tutorial:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/21/creating-a-php-web-role-in-windows-azure.aspx

However I am stuck. I am not entirely sure how to create an instance in the azure management portal, after I have set up the web role on my local machine.

There are currently no instances set up. When I try to set them up, it asks me to upload a package and configuration file. Where can I find these.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment on your question but I can't make comments yet.

When creating a new cloud service do not check the box "Deploy a cloud service package."

If you use + -> Compute -> Cloud Service -> Quick Create it won't ask for a package either.

Once it's done being created you can open it up to download the credential file for Power Shell.

Comment: It's a whole new world for me to explore now! :-D

Comment: I did this, but when I create a production instance under instances, it asks me for a package.

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-47-32-metablogapi/5040.connect_5F00_1E9E5B5D.png - that screen

Comment: @bobo2000 do you want a VM? Because that's something else from a cloud service. Connect is a link to open a remote desktop session into a running cloud service, if you haven't uploaded your package and enabled RDP you won't be able to connect.

Comment: RUNNING
One or more role instances are unhealthy.
1 Instance: 1 Unhealthy - any idea why?

Comment: I couldn't possibly tell you, there are millions of reasons an instance will be listed as un-healthy. You need to just go into that instance from the instance list and see what the issue is. (Instance list is under "Instances" under the main header of the cloud service)